# .NET Core Identiy Explicitly deny a Claim

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, claims-based-identity

Is there a way to explicitly deny a Claim? I need that a user is able to have a claim multiple times, but flag them as "Permitted" or "Denied". If a user has a Claim Permitted and the same Claim Denied, should be considered as not having that Claim.

Right now I have something like this (without Claims):

```
public bool IsEnabled(ApplicationAccess Access, string AccessName)
{
    List<ApplicationAccess> found = new List<ApplicationAccess>();
    found.AddRange(Access.GetChilds.FindAll(childAccess => childAccess.Id == Access.Id));
    return (found.Count > 0 & !found.Exists(childAccess => childAccess.IsDenied == true));
}
public bool IsDenied(ApplicationAccess Access, string AccessName)
{
    List<ApplicationAccess> found = new List<ApplicationAccess>();
    found.AddRange(Access.GetChilds.FindAll(childAccess => childAccess.Id == Access.Id));
    return (found.Count == 0 || found.Exists(childAccess => childAccess.IsDenied == true));
}
public IList<ApplicationAccess> GetEnabledAccesss(ApplicationAccess Access)
{
    List<ApplicationAccess> childs = new List<ApplicationAccess>();
    childs.AddRange(Access.GetChilds);
    foreach (ApplicationAccess deniedChild in childs.FindAll(child => child.IsDenied == true))
    {
    childs.RemoveAll(child => child.Id == deniedChild.Id);
    }
    return childs;
}
```

Comment: not sure what are you trying to accomplish, but why not first add all `permitted` claims and then from the same collection remove all the claims that have same name se `permitted` ones but are `denied`. after that, claims collection can be put into token, cookie, wherever you put them.

Comment: I have a composite set of accesses, (an access grouping accesses, grouping accesses...), so a user can have multiple accesses but could have one of them denied. There is no problem there, but the issue here is that when I implement IUserClaimStore (DataLayer) I don't want to add Business logic there to filter the denied claims, but since NET get the claims directly from the store, not passing thru my business layer, I can't filter them. So I wanted a way to inform .NET that the claim is denied.

Comment: Does the client need information about which claims are denied or is that info something that doesn't need to leave the server?

Comment: It could be either way

Comment: Personally, i would have my implementation of `IUserClaimsStore` to check and remove `denied` claims  from claims collection that will get assigned to User. But, if you don't want to do it for whatever reason and you go with the option that you send those claims to client and get them back and need to check then you could configure Claims check policy. ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/claims

Comment: Yes, I was opting for this last option but if a user has a claim permitted and the same one denied, when I do the authorization, .NET verifies if it the permitted claim exist, I can't have a denied claim that "overrides" the permitted one. I don't know if I am being clear, sorry, english is not my native language.